# Get browser language on startup using Service

Tags: angular

I want to get browser language on application startup. For that I wrote service which looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';

@Injectable()
export class LanguageService {

constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    let browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
    translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|ge/) ? browserLang : 'en');
}
}
```

and in app.module.ts I've added this service:

```
bootstrap: [ AppComponent, [ LanguageService ] ]
```

but when it executes in console appears this error:

> (index):18 Error: (SystemJS) No Directive annotation found on LanguageService(…)

what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should inject LanguageService into AppComponent, not bootstrapping the service.

AppComponent :

```
 constructor(private languageService: LanguageService) { }
```